# recording HD audio using javascript, cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio, web-applications

I am working on a web app where i am able to record and play audio with cordova plugins in my app, but the voice quality is not so good. Audio has a lot of background noise and records at a very low volume, i can barely hear the sound when i play it.

Like WhatsApp can record audio with very high quality with little background noise, can we record a sound of similar quality with Cordova or any other js plugin?

Comment: I think the quality of your sound depends of your phone, so if you have a low quality sound the only solution is to modify that sound in order to remove noise and other things that pollute it.

Comment: Thanks. But if you compare the sound recorded with your phone's mic against the sound sent over whatsapp call while your phone is on speaker, you will find a huge difference.